# browser auto detection of language not working on static nuxt app

Tags: nuxt.js, vuejs3, nuxtjs3, nuxt-i18n

I have a Nuxt 3 application and i have installed the Nuxt i18n module. When i run "npm run dev", the app auto-detect my language but when i generate the static version of the app with "nuxt generate" for production, it doesnt work.

i18n config in nuxt.config.js :

```
  i18n: {
    locales: ['en', 'fr', 'es', "en_gb"],
    defaultLocale: 'en',
    detectBrowserLanguage: {
      useCookie: true,
      cookieKey: 'i18n_redirected',
      redirectOn: 'root', 
    },
    strategy: 'prefix_and_default',
    vueI18n: {
      legacy: false,
      locale: 'en'
      messages: ...
   }
  }
```

I have tried without

detectBrowserLanguage: {
useCookie: true,
cookieKey: 'i18n_redirected',
redirectOn: 'root',
},

or by changing the strategy but without results.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using the v8 (beta) of the module (`npm install @nuxtjs/i18n@next --save-dev`) but by looking the documentation of v7 (`npm install @nuxtjs/i18n`) the options should be the same for browser detection.

This works for me with Lazy-load translations:

```
i18n: {
  // ...
  detectBrowserLanguage: {
    redirectOnRoot: true,
    alwaysRedirect: true
  }
}
```

Note that I added: `alwaysRedirect: true`

With this setting, the `redirectOnRoot` property is respected:
when I visit `http://localhost:3000`, the language is set to the browser language
when I visit `http://localhost:3000/path`, the language is set to the default language