# How to set the default language in Nuxt/i18n based on browser detection?

Tags: nuxt.js, internationalization, i18next, nuxt3, nuxt-i18n

I have been struggling to configure the Nuxt/i18n library in my project.
I would like the website to open in either the user's default language (either "it" or "en") or in English.

Additionally, I want to ensure that when the user changes the language, the newly selected language is maintained when navigating between pages (as it was often switching back to English), and is saved in cookies so that it persists when the user returns to the site.

I have tried various configurations, but I haven't been able to achieve the desired behavior. Here is my current setup:

`nuxt.congif.ts`

```
    modules: ["@nuxtjs/i18n"],
    i18n: {
        vueI18n: "./i18n.config.ts", // if you are using custom path, default
        strategy: "no_prefix",
        detectBrowserLanguage: {
            useCookie: true,
            cookieKey: "i18n_redirected",
            redirectOn: "root", // recommended
        },
        // lazy: true,
        // langDir: "locales/",
        // defaultLocale: "en",
        // locales: [
        //  { code: "en", file: "en.json", name: "English" },
        //  { code: "it", file: "it.json", name: "Italian" },
        // ],
    },
```

`i18n.config.ts`

```
import en from "@/locales/en.json";
import it from "@/locales/it.json";

export default defineI18nConfig(() => ({
    legacy: false,
    locale: "en",
    messages: { en, it },
}));
```

Answer (score 0):

I find your title a bit misleading because the default language is a different thing then the browser detection and the question similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75699786/browser-auto-detection-of-language-not-working-on-static-nuxt-app/76494836) one, so I will post the same answer here.

I'm using the v8 (beta) of the module (`npm install @nuxtjs/i18n@next --save-dev`) but by looking to the documentation of v7 (`npm install @nuxtjs/i18n`) the options should be the same for browser detection.

This works for me with Lazy-load translations:

```
i18n: {
  // ...
  detectBrowserLanguage: {
    redirectOnRoot: true,
    alwaysRedirect: true
  }
}
```

Note that I added: `alwaysRedirect: true`

With this setting, the `redirectOnRoot` property is respected:
when I visit `http://localhost:3000`, the language is set to the browser language
when I visit `http://localhost:3000/path`, the language is set to the default language